# boto3 KeyConditionExpressions must only contain one condition per key

Tags: boto3

I have a trouble with following code. The most difficult to understand is that the expression alway happened when the many query operation happened in a short time interval.
The experssion is as follows:

```
2017-03-05 15:03:59,053 data_sync_worker.py[line:83] ERROR An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: KeyConditionExpressions must only contain one condition per key
ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: KeyConditionExpressions must only contain one condition per key
```

And here is my code:

```
response = self.record_tb.query(
                KeyConditionExpression=Key(self.partition_key).eq(user_id) &
                Key(self.sort_key).between(
                    begin_time+Decimal(CACHE_TIMESTAMP_MIN_STEP),
                    endtime))
```

And here is the table key schema:

```
"KeySchema": [
    {
        "KeyType": "HASH", 
        "AttributeName": "user_id"
    }, 
    {
        "KeyType": "RANGE", 
        "AttributeName": "timestamp"
    }
]
```

So, has anyone met this?

Comment: What does the schema for your table look like?

Comment: I have update the question and add the keyschema @garn

Comment: I've seen this too, always seems to be under heavy load, and never seems reproducible.  It's behaving like a ThroughputExceededException but with a different  label.

Comment: random question @Gary - was your code running with multiple threads/processes?

Answer (score 4):

This error message above can occur from having a malformed query in code, and for many people, that's a reasonable explanation.  However, I've confirmed that you can also get this mysterious and very misleading error message if you run dynamodb `query` using a shared `Table` resource with multiple threads or tasks under a lot of load.  That's what I think is happening in the OP's case.  I've seen this happen both with `boto3` 1.9.82 along with the `pathos` library and with `asyncio` in python 3.6.

To wit, this is something [many of us have suspected](https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/1246) for a long time - boto3 isn't completely thread-safe even if it does often work in practice.

In this particular case, I suspect there's some state that gets corrupted during the query-building process such that the query that *actually* gets submitted to the service endpoint is invalid.  I've not been able to reproduce this on demand; re-running the same code a second time always seems to work.  It would be possible to use the `botocore` logger to capture the actual payloads sent to AWS - that would prove my theory.  However it's really expensive on my end to capture such a large volume of logs, so I just stopped using shared `Table` resources and I stopped seeing the error.

Answer (score 1):

@killthrush answer turned out to be the cause of this error for us.  Basically, as he points out, it appears boto3 is not thread-safe and we were reading from s3 from multiple concurrent threads.

If you are looking for a quick fix, I found the comment by @pedros007 in the link he supplied to work.  Basically when you setup the boto3 s3 client, set the max_pool_connecetions to the amount of workers you are running and so far we have stopped getting the ValidationException error.

```
# code from pedros007
num_threads = 16
cfg = botocore.config.Config(max_pool_connections=num_threads)
client = boto3.client("s3", config=cfg)
futures = {}
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = num_threads) as executor:
    for key in keys:
        f = executor.submit(my_head_object_function, key, client)
        futures[f] = key
```

Others have suggested starting a new session in each thread, which I've tried, and does work but there is a large performance hit.  With the above method the performance is the same.